# Merge the [gods] and [devas] tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

I think when people use the tag [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) it can generally be taken as equivalent to [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas). I cannot think of any instance in which a question pertains to one and not the other, so it might be best to merge them.

As for which one should be merged into which, that's a bit trickier. I personally think that using [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) to refer to *Devas* is misleading, as *Devas* are really mortal *Jivatmas* and do not truly line up with the Western definition of gods.

That being said, [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) only has 2 questions, while [gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) has several. Also, the [devas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devas) tag might not be clear to Westerners browsing this site, although I'm not sure how much of a priority that is.

Either way, I don't think we need both tags, as they're being used to mean effectively the same thing.

Comment: I think I will add tag of **devas** as a synonym to **gods** but certainly will wait for some users to answer

Comment: According to this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devata), we should consider **Devta** and also I think plural of **Deva** is not **Devas** in sanskrit or Hindi.

Comment: I think the plural form of **Deva** is **Devas** only.. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_Sanskrit_grammar).

Comment: I will wait for a day or two, if there is no other pro user backing you up, I will be declining your request (as of now)

Comment: I've declined the request for now as its not clear enough to me, to merge those tags, so you can bring more solid examples next time with your opinion to merge the tags and I will take the necessary actions. Thank you for the request though..

Answer (score 4):

Brahma, Vishnu and Maheshwara are considered the three gods or supreme deities in Hinduism, while the devas are clearly used to refer to the twelve celestial beings. So why merge these two? I would say keep these separate

Comment: But people are using the gods tag to refer to devas.

Comment: Plus anyone who isn't familiar with the term Devas will use gods instead.

Comment: I just did a stackexchange basic search with question with the tag 'gods' and most of the top ones were addressing not the devas, but Hanuman, Shiva and the like. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods

Comment: There is still a significant amount which use it to refer to Devas. If we want them to remain separate, we should be more clear on how [tag:gods] is defined.

Comment: You're right! When I saw the questions over 80% of the 31 questions tagged with God seem to speak about Gods in general rather than devi-devatas. However when I actually went into the question and read through them it was clear that they were using gods to refer to Devas. So I agree with you completely, a more clear definition is good to go.